# How to fix the height of the boxes

Tags: html, css

I am creating a page here: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/course-list/

and I want all of my boxes to have a fixed height.

Right now if I put `height: 500px;` it will just messed up the whole size.

Here's the CSS for that:

```
.col-1-3 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
margin: 2.5%;
 border: 1px solid #dedede;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
font-family: 'Lato', Verdana;
}
```

Any idea how to fixed the height of all the boxes without messing up the design?

Please help!

Comment: have a look at the Masonry plugin

Comment: Try redesigning your boxes with flexbox from the ground up. From what I understand you wish for the box to be vertically "stretched", so you have the red botton always on the container's bottom.

Comment: there are multiple ways to implement equal height colums, some of them listed here: https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/. You can combine this with a max-height and work with ellipsis if you want to cap the height.

Comment: Some messing around in dev tools and I established one method. Add a specific height to `.col-1-3`, I tried around 560px. Give the same class `position: relative`. Then on the buttons, give them `position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: <side-margin>; right: <side-margin>; width: calc(100% - <side-margin>*2 )`. (<side-margin>*2 being the actual value, not the string. So 10px margin would mean 20px in calc

Comment: first of all, dont change bootstrap grid system classes. make your own class. second, try Masonry plugins.

Comment: Do you know John Doe Cross? They're asking about this same problem on the same site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521803/fix-size-of-every-boxes?noredirect=1#comment72180838_42521803

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height: 550px;` on `.col-1-3` (no fixed `height`)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I will write a little javascript to match a bunch of elements to the tallest one of the group, like this:

```
function fixHeights() {
        matchHeights(1);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () { fixHeights(); })
    $(window).load(function () { fixHeights(); })
    $(window).resize(function () { fixHeights(); })

    function matchHeights(ind) {
        var topHeight = 0;
        $("div[data-match='" + ind + "']").height("");
        $("div[data-match='" + ind + "']").each(function () {
            topHeight = Math.max(topHeight, $(this).height());
        });
        $("div[data-match='" + ind + "']").height(topHeight);
    }
```

What "matchHeights" will do is find elements with a matching attribute of data-match-# and match their heights.  So you could add data-match-1 to your div's and then call matchHeights(1).

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to achieve what you want is using `flexbox`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-row .box {
  flex: 0 0 33.333%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aliquam reprehenderit, quidem ex aut harum iste quas unde earum suscipit.
  </div>
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore aliquam.
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want spaces - you could take a look at this popular plugins - or similar

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/
http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Assigning `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` on the parent will make all of the elements in a row be the same height - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpQLxv

```
.wpb_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```