# Fix size of every boxes

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project here: https://jsfiddle.net/x3rceway/

And I am stuck cause I can't make all of my boxes have a fixed size even there is extra space on the bottom for as long the button is always down below. I am expecting to have something like this:

[CLICK HERE IMAGE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oku6M.jpg)

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-1-3">

<img src="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/The-Bitcoin-Transaction-Landscape.jpg" />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">BC 101 - The Bitcoin Transaction COURSE</h3>
<p>This course covers the basics of what Bitcoin is and how the Blockchain works, how to use a Bitcoin Wallet and why Bitcoin is important.</p>
<a href="https://xt348.infusionsoft.com/app/orderForms/The-Bitcoin-Transaction" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">PURCHASE COURSE &rarr;</button></a>

</div>

<div class="col-1-3">

<img src="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Intro-Logo-Horizontal.jpg" alt="" />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">TR 101 - Introduction to Bitcoin Trading</h3>
<p>This course is the introductory course for Bitcoin trading. It will teach you the basics and several of the important tools and need-to-know issues and topics to get up and running.</p>
<a href="https://xt348.infusionsoft.com/app/orderForms/Introduction-to-Bitcoin-Trading" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">PURCHASE COURSE &rarr;</button></a>

</div>


<div class="col-1-3">
<img src="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Pro-Logo-Horizontal.jpg" />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">TR 201 - The Professional Bitcoin Trading Course</h3>
<p>This course covers all of our offerings in one. This is for entrepreneurs who are serious about making serious income through Bitcoin trading. This course teaches how to get set up, what to watch out for, copy to paste into your ads, how to manage your customers, how to not get scammed, how to scale, etc. This also includes an inclusion into a private traders group with your class so you can discuss and figure out new ways to make money together.</p>
<a href="https://xt348.infusionsoft.com/app/orderForms/The-Professional-Bitcoin-Trading-Course" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">PURCHASE COURSE &rarr;</button></a>

</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div class="col-1-3">
<img src="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Pro-Logo-Horizontal.jpg" />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Bitcoin Trading Bootcamp</h3>
<p>This is similar in nature to The Professional Bitcoin Trading Course in the sense that we will cover all of the same topics covered in that course, plus up to date relevant ones, live and in person. You will also get a chance to watch pro traders trade live and learn how they manage several trades at the same time, what to do, what not to do, etc. This also includes an inclusion into a private traders group with your class so you can discuss and figure out new ways to make money together.</p>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">PURCHASE COURSE &rarr;</button></a>

</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.col-1-3 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
margin: 2.5%;
 border: 2px solid #000;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
font-family: 'Lato', Verdana;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  margin: 0;
}
h3 {
  margin: 15px auto;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

p{
line-height: 16px;
margin: 10px auto;
}
h4 {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

}
.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
margin-top: 22px;
background: #DD374D;
}

button.btn-block{
background: #DD374D;
font-family: 'Roboto';
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
}

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-1-3 {
    width: 44%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .col-1-3 {
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

How can I fixed the height of the boxes without affecting my design and the responsiveness? Please use my JSFIDDLE to show me how to fixed it.

Comment: Are you Matthew Matt? This question was just asked - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521189/how-to-fix-the-height-of-the-boxes

Comment: Whos that Michael?

Comment: Why don't you ask them? I just noticed someone else was asking for layout help on the same page of the same site.

Answer (score 1):

Give the boxes a parent and assign `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to the parent, and the height of the boxes in each row will match.

```css
.col-1-3 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
margin: 2.5%;
 border: 2px solid #000;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
font-family: 'Lato', Verdana;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  margin: 0;
}
h3 {
  margin: 15px auto;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

p{
line-height: 16px;
margin: 10px auto;
}
h4 {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

}
.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
margin-top: 22px;
background: #DD374D;
}

button.btn-block{
background: #DD374D;
font-family: 'Roboto';
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
}

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-1-3 {
    width: 44%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .col-1-3 {
    width: 94%;
  }
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<div class="col-1-3">

<img src="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/The-Bitcoin-Transaction-Landscape.jpg" />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">BC 101 - The Bitcoin Transaction COURSE</h3>
<p>This course covers the basics of what Bitcoin is and how the Blockchain works, how to use a Bitcoin Wallet and why Bitcoin is important.</p>
<a href="https://xt348.infusionsoft.com/app/orderForms/The-Bitcoin-Transaction" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">PURCHASE COURSE &rarr;</button></a>

</div>

<div class="col-1-3">

<img src="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Intro-Logo-Horizontal.jpg" alt="" />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">TR 101 - Introduction to Bitcoin Trading</h3>
<p>This course is the introductory course for Bitcoin trading. It will teach you the basics and several of the important tools and need-to-know issues and topics to get up and running.</p>
<a href="https://xt348.infusionsoft.com/app/orderForms/Introduction-to-Bitcoin-Trading" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">PURCHASE COURSE &rarr;</button></a>

</div>


<div class="col-1-3">
<img src="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Pro-Logo-Horizontal.jpg" />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">TR 201 - The Professional Bitcoin Trading Course</h3>
<p>This course covers all of our offerings in one. This is for entrepreneurs who are serious about making serious income through Bitcoin trading. This course teaches how to get set up, what to watch out for, copy to paste into your ads, how to manage your customers, how to not get scammed, how to scale, etc. This also includes an inclusion into a private traders group with your class so you can discuss and figure out new ways to make money together.</p>
<a href="https://xt348.infusionsoft.com/app/orderForms/The-Professional-Bitcoin-Trading-Course" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">PURCHASE COURSE &rarr;</button></a>

</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div class="col-1-3">
<img src="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Pro-Logo-Horizontal.jpg" />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Bitcoin Trading Bootcamp</h3>
<p>This is similar in nature to The Professional Bitcoin Trading Course in the sense that we will cover all of the same topics covered in that course, plus up to date relevant ones, live and in person. You will also get a chance to watch pro traders trade live and learn how they manage several trades at the same time, what to do, what not to do, etc. This also includes an inclusion into a private traders group with your class so you can discuss and figure out new ways to make money together.</p>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">PURCHASE COURSE &rarr;</button></a>

</div>
</div>
```