# How can I add flexbox on my Wordpress Site

Tags: html, wordpress, css, flexbox

Hey guys I am trying to apply flexbox on my wordpress site.

Based on what I know Flexbox is a shorthand of "Flexible Box Layout Module", which is a CSS3 module, standardized by the World Wide Web Consortium.

So I don't have to install anything, compliant browsers support it natively but for some reason it won't work on my site: http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/course-list/

Currently I am using flex on my codes:

```
<div class="flex">
<div class="col-1-3">

<img src="http://americanbitcoinacademy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/The-Bitcoin-Transaction-Landscape.jpg" />
<h3 style="text-align: center;">BC 101 - The Bitcoin Transaction COURSE</h3>
<p>This course covers the basics of what Bitcoin is and how the Blockchain works, how to use a Bitcoin Wallet and why Bitcoin is important.</p>
<a href="https://xt348.infusionsoft.com/app/orderForms/The-Bitcoin-Transaction" target="_blank"><button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">PURCHASE COURSE &rarr;</button></a>

</div>

</div>


.col-1-3 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
margin: 2.5%;
 border: 1px solid #dedede;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
font-family: 'Lato', Verdana;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  margin: 0;
}
h3 {
  margin: 15px auto;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

p{
line-height: 16px;
margin: 10px auto;
}
h4 {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

}
.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
margin-top: 22px;
background: #DD374D;
}

button.btn-block{
background: #DD374D;
font-family: 'Roboto';
margin-bottom: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
}

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-1-3 {
    width: 44%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .col-1-3 {
    width: 94%;
  }
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Which will do the trick to have equal size of the boxes NO MATTER HOW LONG IS THE CONTENT on that page by default. 
Any idea why does the flexbox doesnt work?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why haven't you accepted any answers to your questions since 1/24?

Comment: Which answer Michael?

Comment: You've asked 10 since 1/24 and none have accepted answers.

Comment: Not sure which question you are talking about.

Comment: The last ten questions you have asked... People will avoid answering your questions if you don't ever accept any solutions.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, i did not notice that. I will check on those later.

Comment: I have checked the previous questions and I did accepted the answers.

Comment: @ObsidianAge what tipped me off was they asked this question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521189/how-to-fix-the-height-of-the-boxes and then an hour later basically the same question was asked by a new user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521803/fix-size-of-every-boxes. Neither accepted an answer and today Matt's using the answer I gave to "John Doe Cross" about this site/layout yesterday.

Comment: @MichaelCoker -- A very interesting find! Definitely the same user, though why he'd create another account like that is beyond me. Also, I've answered a number of questions (many times it's been a question you have answered as well, actually) where no solution has been marked as accepted, despite the problem definitely being solved. I guess it's worth checking the asker's 'acceptance ratio'! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works. You are probably not testing in a flex box capable browser:
http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

[image]

To align buttons to bottom:

```
.col-1-3 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 40px; /* offset height of button */
}
button.btn-block{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Comment: I amended the answer with a screenshot from Safari. Is this not the desired outcome?

Comment: Nope. the desired outcome is that all of them will have the same box size.

Comment: Not sure I understand, are we talking about the grey rounded box?

Comment: correct. do you see the border grey? they must all be equal sizes.

Comment: All three boxes are the same height and width in the screenshot I posted? Do you want to lessen the whitespace in the left two? or align the buttons to the bottom?

Comment: Is that a screenshot from Safari? it should work on chrome too right?

Comment: Yes and same result in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 for Mac

Comment: How can I push the buttons and make them fixed on the bottom like the last image? I think thats the right question.